# Runnable hangs UI thread on Android

Tags: java, android, handler, runnable

I have a piece of code that is run every hour. The code does some SQL tasks on a local SQLite database on the device. Sometimes this task is a little more cumbersome than others, and when it is, the application hangs enough time that a "is not responding" dialog opens up and gives me the option to wait or close the app.

This is my code

```
UpdateTimerCleanUp = new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        TextView updatedTxt = findViewById(R.id.updated_txt);
        updatedTxt.setText("Performing database history cleanup..");
        archive.archieveHistory();
        ArchiveHandler.postDelayed(UpdateTimerCleanUp, CleanUpCycle);
    }
};
ArchiveHandler.postDelayed(UpdateTimerCleanUp, CleanUpCycle);
```

I'm using a handler to call the runnable every hour (`CleanUpCycle`). That part works, but why does it hang my UI? As i understand it a runnable is run on another thread?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Handler`s run `Runnable`s on whatever thread the `Handler` was created on.  So if you created `ArchiveHandler` on the main thread, it will run the `UpdateTimerCleanUp` code on the main trough.  I'm not sure what your `archieveHistory()` method does exactly, but I'm guessing it takes long enough to run that it's causing the application-not-responding error due to blocking the main thread.

To solve it, you should use some means of background execution that suits your needs (Executors, Threads, etc.).

Comment: This is indeed what is happening. The ArchiveHandler is created in MainActivity. Since i update a textfield present in MainActivity, should i instead create the thread inside the runnable? Or should i make the thread outside of it and call post on the textview?

Comment: I think either would be fine.  Assuming you're using postDelayed as the primary timing mechanism, I'd lean toward creating the thread (or whatever you do for background execution) from the runnable.